# How to resolve a variable inside a variable?

Tags: ansible

Considering this Ansible task:

```
- name: Set some kernel parameters
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/home/cloud-user/{{item}}.hostsubnet.json"
    regexp: '^(.*hostIP\".*)\"10.*\"(.*)$'
    line: \1"{{hostvars['{{item}}']['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address']}}"\2
    backrefs: yes
  with_items: "{{ groups.nodes }}"
```

I am trying to loop over the all hosts in group [nodes].
For each node, I would like to fetch an IP from facts, and use that IP
as a substitute string for lineinfile regexp.

But this would not work. Looks like nested variables are not possible.
Is it possible to resolve the nested variable?

I am getting this error with a code:

```
fatal: [master-0.ocp-36-2.teco.dev.a.tecdomain.net]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true
}

MSG:

the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a 
variable that is undefined. The error was: 
'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVars object' has no attribute '{{item}}'

The error appears to have been in 
'/var/lib/ansible/playbooks/hostsubnet.yml': line 27, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: Set some kernel parameters
      ^ here
```

Comment: For the love of Cthulhu, this is a great example of how terrible `lineinfile` is. Even if it was working it should be replaced with templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying refer to a key in `hostvars` using a string `{{item}}`.

You should use a variable name `item` instead:

```
line: \1"{{hostvars[item]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address']}}"\2
```

---

You seem also to be confused with the terminology: you try to refer to a variable value inside a Jinja2 expression (i.e. what's wrapped in `{{ }}`). The answer to such a question is: by using variable name, plain.

Comment: Yes ineeded confused. Thanks for clarification.